# How to use an svg shape to mask an image?

Tags: css, image, svg

I have an SVG shape that I would like to use as a mask so that every image that I add to it will be sort of inside that shape.

This is my shape that I would like to use as a mask:

[image: Image to use as a mask]

This is my svg code to get that mask but with black color

```html
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="157.000000pt" height="163.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 157.000000 163.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
   <metadata>
      My svg Mask
   </metadata>
   <g transform="translate(0.000000,163.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
      fill="#000000" stroke="none">
      <path d="M373 1197 c-355 -355 -363 -363 -363 -402 0 -39 8 -47 363 -402 355
         -355 363 -363 402 -363 39 0 47 8 402 363 355 355 363 363 363 402 0 39 -8 47
         -363 402 -355 355 -363 363 -402 363 -39 0 -47 -8 -402 -363z"/>
   </g>
</svg>
```

And this is the final result that I would like to achieve by adding an image

[image: Final result expected]

**How to make any image I add to my website be masked by the svg file or the red shape in order for them to be displayed like this one ?**

[image: Final result expected]

Comment: Don't you want a clipPath rather than a mask?

Comment: I will be glad to that Only that I don't know how to get that exact form with ClipPath. Do you have an Idea of how to get that exact form ? Tks

Comment: rotate(45) transform on a rect element with rx set

Comment: Thanks a lot but I could not come up with a solution that worked cross browser. Can you provide me with a jsfiddle for this ? I am not an expert with clipPath cross browser. Thanks

Comment: @RobertLongson This is what I was able to come up with 
http://codepen.io/manofgod/pen/YXbKLr 
However this is not compatible with IE for example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here's an example of applying an SVG clipping-path through CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.test {
  height: 160px;
  width: 170px;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#shape);
  clip-path: url(#shape);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="shape">
            <path transform="translate(0.000000,163.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" d="M373 1197 c-355 -355 -363 -363 -363 -402 0 -39 8 -47 363 -402 355
-355 363 -363 402 -363 39 0 47 8 402 363 355 355 363 363 363 402 0 39 -8 47
-363 402 -355 355 -363 363 -402 363 -39 0 -47 -8 -402 -363z" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
<img class='test' src='http://placekitten.com/640/480' />
```

One thing to remember is that you can't have a `g` (grouping tag) inside clipping mask or it won't display;

for this reason , in your ex., you'll find the transform property directly on the path instead then on the g tag.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/vxum7dnn/)

Comment: + 1 For that. But i have a problem, even when i copy and paste the code exactly, it does not work except it is on jsfiddle or codepen. But it does not work in my php page especially when i use a direct url unless i use the url i have used on codepen or jsfiddle and also it works only on the first image. The second image does not display. And if there is a text that precedes it, it covers the image. Can you help me find out why ? Tks

Comment: try making another question 'why doesn't svg work if integrated in php' (posting sourcecode and all the details)

Comment: BTW remember this solution isn't currently supported in IE, but there should be a polyfill for that